# Is there a simpler way to write this React code

Tags: reactjs

Need this code more simplified. All I wanna do is have an onClick event perform an action, but the code seems overcomplicated for what I wanna do:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Comment extends Component{
    constructor(){

      super();
      this.state= {name:''};

      this.display = this.display.bind(this);
    }


display(){
  this.setState({name:'Test2'});
}

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.display}>Click me</button>
          <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
        </div>
      )
  }

}

export default Comment;
```

Comment: This is a simple and basic code

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [React 16.8](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook), then a simpler implementation as a functional component based on the [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) is possible like so:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

/* Define functional equivalent of Comment component */
const Comment = () => {

    /* Setup name state getter/setter via useState hook */
    const [name, setName] = useState('')

    /* Render comment JSX */
    return (<div>
        <button onClick={() => setName('Test2')}>Click me</button>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>)
}

export default Comment;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to try `Hooks` **(Hooks are added in V16.8)**, then [arrow function](https://medium.com/@oleg008/arrow-functions-in-react-f782d11460b4) is also a simple one,

```
class Comment extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {name: ''}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({name: 'Test2'})}>Click me</button>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-79b8f?fontsize=14)

Comment: If you wanted to take it a step further, you could avoid the `constructor()`:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-93zdd

Comment: @DacreDenny You are right, but this is kept as it is as in OP keeping in mind there can be other function's or might have other state in future.

Comment: Thanks Dacre. I like that